# is there any evidence that ばら is commonly understood as gay

Tags: word-choice, words, etymology, homonyms

My japanese speaking but not native friend talked about a foreign friend whose name translates to "ばら" (bara - 薔薇) with some native japanese.
They quickly objected that she shouldn't call that friend ばら as this means "gay" (homosexual) in japanese.
I couldn't find any evidence for this and am curious now.
The only thing I found is that the first gay magazine is called "barazoku" which could be shortened to "bara". Maybe becoming a synonym for gay.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barazoku

Is "ばら" an actual word with the meaning "gay"? Or is it just a common term? Or is it just common in the LGBT community and most japanese would be clueless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes 薔薇 implied gay several decades ago, and I believe most Japanese adults were more or less aware of this in those days. It's no longer a common metaphor.

Note that 薔薇 was argot for real gay relationship, if I understand correctly. Fictional male-male romance enjoyed by female audience (still known as [yaoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaoi_fandom) outside of Japan) has not been referred to as 薔薇. See [this article](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok2o.htm) for details.